# How can I get my Mac to recognize a downloaded Joomla extension as a ZIP file instead of a folder?

Tags: macos, joomla, zip

When I download a Joomla extension to my Mac (e.g. http://www.admiror-design-studio.com/admiror-joomla-extensions/admiror-gallery) I can't upload it via the `Package File` option because my Mac sees the download as a folder.

How do I get it to stop doing that?  It's driving me insane!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either re-compress it using right-click, compress. Or turn off 'auto open save files' in safari preferences.

Comment: Fantastic answer my friend, and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

I often have this problem with Wordpress plugins.

When you download a compressed file (e.g. .zip, .gz, etc.) OS X tries to be useful and expands it with the archive manager. Then all you need to do is right click the folder (or CTRL Click) and hit compress. You should java a ZIP file you can then upload without doing anything to it.